# How can view the swagger ui for Azure API app

Tags: c#, azure, swagger, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps

I am creating an Azure API app on Visual Studio 2015. when i hit browse and redirected to `http://localhost:3012/` if i add `swagger` to the url nothing happens : `http://localhost:3012/swagger`

it seems I need to add the `/docs/v1` for a full address : `http://localhost:3012/swagger/docs/v1` . Shouldn't there be like an automatic URL routing when i add /swagger to load swagger page. 
Also, i am only able to view the json schema, if i browser to the UI `http://localhost:3012/swagger/ui` the page doesn't load.

The API app builds successfully. is there anything missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pedro, above, has provided a perfect answer for enabling SwaggerUi.
As for your question regarding the URL "`swagger/docs/v1`"

This is the default URL used by Swashbuckle to return Swagger 2.0 JSON metadata for the API

The `SwaggerConfig.cs` file is created when you install the Swashbuckle package in a project. You can find it in the folder "App_Start" . It provides a number of ways to configure Swashbuckle. I haven't checked if you can change that default URL or do URL rerouting for it.

**Edited:**

The default route templates for the Swagger docs and swagger-ui are "swagger/docs/{apiVersion}" and "swagger/ui/{*assetPath}" respectively. You can change these so long as the provided templates include the relevant route parameters - {apiVersion} and {*assetPath}.
For example: the URL to swagger-ui will be myswag/index.

> httpConfiguration
>       .EnableSwagger("docs/{apiVersion}/swagger", c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "A title for your API"))
>
> .EnableSwaggerUi("myswag/{*assetPath}");

You can read more about it here in the GitHub repo: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle

Answer (score 7):

In the configuration of your WebAPI project (`SwaggerConfig.cs` in the folder `App_Start`), you have to enable the Swagger UI. It is commented out as default behavior.

Just open the configuration, search for:

```
                /*
                    })
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                    {
                */
```

and disable the comments in the lines above and under it

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating API using Template **Azure API App** in visual studio,  you just need to un-comment few lines from SwaggerConfig.cs file to activate Swagger for your API application.

1. In your solution look for the file 'SwaggerConfig.cs'

   *'VSSolution' > App_Start > SwaggerConfig.cs*
2. Look for **EnableSwaggerUi**  and remove comments for below line of code

   ```
               /*
                   })
               .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                   {
               */
   ```
3. That's it, No Other Configuration Required.

   Just run the application :
   http://localhost:57452/*swagger*

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and was misled a bit by these answers although I saw that they were admittedly entirely correct in the end.

Note the following:

- Don't mistake the `.EnableSwagger` setting for the `EnableSwaggerUi`
  setting in `SwaggerConfig.cs`.

  - The former is on by default and comes at the beginning of the
    `SwaggerConfig.cs` file
  - the latter is commented out by default and buried in a lot of other comments. It cost me quite some time before I noticed that there were actually **two** settings.
- The `.EnableSwagger` setting causes **raw JSON** to be emitted on your application url  `https://yourapp.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/v1` - which is not a great help.
- While the `.EnableSwaggerUi` setting is what causes the **Swagger UI** to appear on your url `https://yourapp.azurewebsites.net/swagger`